# Questions about using Z3Py online to apply the Routh-Hurwitz Theorem

Tags: z3

Example 1:

[image]

We apply the RH theorem using the following code

```
K = Real('K')
print simplify(And(12 - 3*K >0 , 20 + 0.25*K >0))
```

and the output is:

```
¬(K ≥ 4) ∧ ¬(K ≤ -80)
```

Example 2:

[image]

We apply the RH Theorem using the following code

```
K, a1, a2, a3 = Reals('K a1 a2 a3')
a1 = 20 + 1.5*K
a2 = 4
a3 = 4*K -100
print simplify(And(a1 > 0 , a3 > 0, a1*a2 > a3))
```

and the output is

```
¬(K ≤ -40/3) ∧ ¬(K ≤ 25) ∧ ¬(K ≤ -90)
```

Example 3:

[image]

We apply the RH Theorem using the following code

```
K = Real('K')
a1 = 10
a2 = 30 - 2.4*K
a3 =  2
a4 = 100 + 5*K
print simplify(And(a4 > 0, a1*a2*a3 > a3**2 + a4*a1**2))
```

and the output is

```
¬(K ≤ -20) ∧ ¬(K ≥ -2351/137)
```

Example 4:

[image]

We apply the RH Theorem using the following code

```
u, s, d, g, N, b , a = Reals('u s d g N b a')
c1 = 2*u + s + d + g
prove(Implies(And(u > 0, s > 0, d >0, g >0), c1 > 0))
c2 = u*g + u**2 + s*u + 2*d*u + s*d + s*g + d*g
c3 = d*u**2 - N*a*b*s + d*u*g + s*d*u + s*d*g
prove(Implies(And(u > 0, s > 0, d >0, g >0, a >0, b > 0, N >0), c1*c2 > c3))
```

and the output is:

```
proved
proved
```

the remanent RH condition :  c3 > 0  leads to

[image]

Example 5:

[image]

We apply the RH Theorem using the following code

```
u, s1, s2, d, g, N, b , a = Reals('u s1 s2 d g N b a')
c1 = d + 3*u + s1 + g + s2
prove(Implies(And(u > 0, s1 > 0, s2 > 0, d >0, g >0), c1 > 0))
c2 = s2*g + 3*d*u + d*g + d*s1+ s1*s2 + 3*u**2 + 2*s2*u + 2*s1*u+ s1*g + 2*u*g + d*s2 
c3 = 2*d*u*g + s1*u*g + 2*d*s2*u + 3*d*u**2 + d*g*s1 + s1*s2*g + u**3 + u*s2*g +  2*d*s1*u + s1*s2*u + g*u**2 + d*g*s2 + s1*u**2 + d*s1*s2 + s2*u**2
prove(Implies(And(u > 0, s1 > 0, s2 >0, d >0, g >0, a >0, b > 0, N >0), c3 > 0))
c4 = d*g*u**2 + d*s2*u**2 + s1*d*u*g + s1*d*s2*u + s1*d*s2*g - N*a*b*s1*s2 + d*u**3 +  s1*d*u**2 + d*u*s2*g
prove(Implies(And(u > 0, s1 > 0, s2 >0, d >0, g >0, a >0, b > 0, N >0), c1*c2*c3 >  c3**2 + c4*c1**2))
```

and the output is:

```
proved
proved
proved
```

It can also try it online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/nFDu).

the remanent RH condition : c4 > 0 leads to

[image]

Questions:

1. Please let me know if you know a more efficient code for this kind of problems
2. How to simplify the outputs for the examples 1, 2 and 3.
3. For the exampple 4, how to solve c3 > 0 respect to b using Z3Py and then to obtain the  formula for Ro
4. For the exampple 5, how to solve c4 > 0 respect to b using Z3Py and then to obtain the  formula for Ro

Many thanks.

Comment: Juan: We appreciate your posts. However, StackOverflow is meant to be a site for questions and answers. Not clear if you are asking anything here at all.


Maybe there's a need for a Z3 related site where people can post snippets of code that uses Z3 for interesting things and have relevant discussions; something like a sub-reddit.

Comment: Manty thanks, my post has now the required form.